# setting Preemptive authentication for rest api using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I am using below code to test Rest API using UFT(VBScript).

```
url ="http://*********"
username = "test"
Pwd = "pwd"
inputfilepath  = "C:\TApps\Message.txt"
Set fso = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fl = fso.OpenTextFile(inputfilepath)
strMsg = fl.readall
Set f1 = Nothing
fl.Close
Set fso = Nothing

Set restReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
restReq.Open "POST", url, False,username,Pwd
restReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/json"
'restReq.SetRequestHeader "Authentication", "preemptive"
''restReq.setRequestHeader "PreemptiveAuthentiction",true
 restReq.setRequestHeader "Accept","application/json"
 restReq.Send strMsg
msgbox restReq.responsetext
```

I am getting error message as in `responseText` as

```
[{"error-code":"1","error_msg":"error when reading the key:null}]
```

There is no issue with json string as manually I am getting the proper response. After doing some analysis, I came to know 'Preemptive Authentication' should be `true` for my request. Tried by setting using 'SetRequestHeader', but no luck.

Comment: *”After doing some analysis, i came to known 'Preemptive Authentication' should be true for my request”* - Can you elaborate on how you came to this conclusion, is it specified in the API documentation, can you link it?

Comment: Hi, When i tested API with by creating API test in UFT I got the proper response when 'Use Premeetive Authentication' as true. If it is false, I am getting the same error as mentioned in earlier post.

Comment: Check following link for how to set auth header https://zanstra.home.xs4all.nl/inTec/ServerXMLHTTP.htm
http.setRequestHeader "Authorization", _
  "Basic " & Base64Encode("username:password")